# How to divide the height of an element on 3 elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html code:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.parent {
    width: 15%;
    height: -webkit-fill-available
}

.child {
    height: 33.33%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I tried the `display:table` for "parent" & `display:table-row` for "child" , but it didn't work.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use flexbox, and don't forget to set `.parent` to `height:100%`.

The main advantages of using flexbox:

- You don't have to deal with overflow problem, say there is more content in one row that couldn't fit 1/3 of the entire container height, it will simply expand the row automatically, and all the remaining free space will still be evenly distributed.
- You can easily add or remove a row without changing the CSS, they will be evenly distributed based on the number or child divs.
- If you need one or more rows to be shorter or taller, you can just use `flex` or `flex-grow` or `flex-basis` to adjust accordingly.
- Plus, if you haven't heard of flexbox yet, you'll be amazed how powerful it is once you entered the flexbox world.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `height: 100%;` and `margin: 0;` (to reset the default margin) to `html` and `body`, then 100% height for the parent and 33.33% for the children. No flex or table needed...

The main important thing is that the parent needs a defined height for the percentage values of the children to become effective. And if that parent height is a percentage value, also the parent of the parent needs a defined height. If you only use percentages, that goes up to `body` and `html`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  height: 33.33%;
  background: #fa0;
}

.child:first-child {
  background: #0fa;
}

.child:last-child {
  background: #af0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, just put min-width to see it in action.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .parent{
            height:100%;
        }

        .child{
            height:32%;
            border:1px solid black; 
            min-width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `32 + 32 + 32 = 96`

Comment: @Turnip [Indeed, quite so...](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/35210952/indeed-quite-so.jpg)

Comment: Just put 33.33%, I just wanted to show how you can make the height dynamic. I put 32 because I was adding a 1px border just to make you clear that height is actually working

Comment: @ShreerajKarki `height: calc(100% / 3 - 2px);` then

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I just wanted to show the code dude, the person who asked the question can put as much percent he wants the height to be.. peace out ..